# Mat dialog not keeping action buttons in view on mobile screen

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

When opening a mat dialog from a mobile device I want the header and action buttons to remain visible at all times.

The content in the dialog is scrolling as expected but I want the action buttons to stay shown so the user can easily access them at any time.

See the below stackblitz that describes my issue.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/dgjvllndexp?file=app%2Fdialog-content-example.html

Comment: Could you try removing "height: '350px'", i.e. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxunmx?file=app%2Fdialog-content-example.ts